# How can I share in-app purchases between iPad and iPhone app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I created an iPhone app which is already in the AppStore and it contains in-app purchases. Now I want to launch an iPad version of that same app as a separate app.

I really would like that customers who purchased items in the iPhone version, also have them available on the iPad version. I know this is possible, because I have seen it working with another app:

- in the iPhone version of that app I purchased some items
- I bought a separate iPad version of that app
- I clicked "Restore purchases"
- All my purchases from the iPhone app appeared!

It could be that they use a workaround using their own server, but I hope that I don't have to do something like that.

Comment: It can be possible if you are hoping to release it as a universal app. I mean use the same bundle id and stuff. Don't make it as a separate app

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want an universal app. And the example I gave was an app that is also not universal.

Comment: You can fetch the restored prurchases only, if the apps have same bundle id. Because, the products you are creating are registered with the bundle id. So, either you can chose same bundle id or store the pruchased items in a server.

Comment: I guess it's the only way... Bit still, how do I do that? I have nothing to uniquely identify the user with.